# How do I get a standalone SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)?

Tags: software-rec, sql-server, ssms

I don't want to install the entire SQL Server (2005 or 2008) on my Virtual PC (saving space), yet I need the SSMS to connect to external databases.

What are my options?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start up the installer but only select the "Client Tools" portion of the installer. That's an option after it chugs through the pre-req checks, as I recall.

Answer (score 0):

There is an "express" version of SSMS 2008 that I use to connect to my remote servers from my local desktop:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593